# Is there any way to prevent/stop the unrender event in an Aura component?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, lightning, aura

I'm trying to conditionally prevent the closing of a QuickAction. I've tried overriding the unrender event in the Aura Renderer but to no avail.

```
({
unrender: function (component) {
    
    console.log('unrender event');
    var deleteOnClose = component.get('v.deleteOnClose');
    console.log('deleteOnClose:', component.get('v.deleteOnClose'));
    if (!deleteOnClose) {
        this.superUnrender();
        return;
    }
}
```

})

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use [`lightning:unsavedChanges`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:unsavedChanges/documentation) to ask the user if they want to navigate away, since closing the Quick Action should change the URL, thus triggering this event. Note that if the user agrees to move on, then you still can't force the Quick Action to stay open.